# jQuery Mobile - $.camelCase is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

At the moment, I try to play with jQuery Mobile but it won't work...
All I do is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>                                                                
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                                               
    <head>                                                                                
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.0b1.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js"></script>
    </head>                                                                               
    <body>                                                                                
        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>My first jQM Page</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <p>This is the Content</p>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div><!-- /page -->
~                           
    </body>                                                                               
</html>
```

Firebug always tells me

> $.camelCase is not a function [Break On This Error] return
>   $.camelCase( $.mobile.ns + prop );

in jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js (line 1967)

Can you help me? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`camelCase` is a jQuery core function that jQuery Mobile is using. It exists in the latest version of jQuery (1.6.2), but doesn't seem to exist in the old version (1.4.2) that you're using. I'm not sure when it was introduced, but it seems to have been moved into the core relatively recently.

So, upgrade your jQuery library. The jQuery Mobile site doesn't seem to specify a minimum jQuery version, but their examples use 1.6.1, so I'd upgrade to at least that version -- I'd say you'd be best just grabbing the latest and greatest, 1.6.2.